# Can a neural net approach be used for association/clustering of odd shaped clusters?

Tags: neural-network, cluster-analysis

I have a process that generates "strings" of (x,y) data points from multiple sources.  The data points need to be grouped according to their source, with the number of sources unknown.  The picture below shows a cartoon example, with the points colored by source.  The "coloring" is what we want an automated process to do.

[image]

They aren't always overlapping or oscillatory as in the picture.  We have various traditional algorithms to do this, but they break down with long gaps between data, even though people can generally see the patterns quite easily.

Is there a neural network architecture that would apply to this problem?  It seems to me that a neural net, in principle, could learn the kinds of shapes the clusters generally take in our application.  Training data is plentiful.

Comment: this would probably be better on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd argue this is underspecified. This might as well be two fish like shapes: ∝

And I'd argue the average step size is smaller than the given coloring.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't tell you enough to write a custom algorithm. The idea would be that a neural network could learn by example the details, such as that no single source will generate two y values at the same x, and that smooth strings are more likely than discontinuous ones.  These things are quickly obvious to people who see multiple examples.